# opening pdf file in external storage in default pdf viewer app on a button click

Tags: java, android, file, pdf

on a button click below function is executed , I gave it storage permission when prompted to. without the StartActivity line it's not crashing , can anyone help me with this , i want  to open a specific existing file with device default pdf viewer. ther is no error with permissions or file existance or pdf viwer application presence.

public void openfile(View v) {

```
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_MEDIA);
    } else {

        File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Zio app/" + "notes.pdf");  // -> filename = maven.pdf
        if (pdfFile.exists()) {

            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
            Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            try {
                startActivity(pdfIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Application available to view PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(NewActivity.this, "No such file exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of times , it didn't even shown a "no application found to view pdf " error
straightaway its crashing

Comment: Your code should produce a `FileUriExposedException`. Use a `FileProvider` to serve your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I got the answer , now its working , Had to use FileProvider , now it's more like

if anyone facing same problem let me know I will post step by step solution

public void openfile(View v) {

```
    if (!checkstoragepermission()) {
        requestReadpermission();`
    }else {
        File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Zio 
       app/" + "/materials/"+"notes.pdf");  // -> filename = maven.pdf
        if (pdfFile.exists()) {

            File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" 
            + "Zio app" ,"materials");
            File newFile = new File(imagePath, "notes.pdf");
            Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, 
             "com.example.zio.fileprovider", newFile);

            Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | 
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(pdfIntent, "Open File");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | 
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Application available to 
                 view PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(NewActivity.this, "No such file exists", 
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: the permissions has to be added to both the intents in my case. Wow, browsed so many tutorials and check the existence of files several times until I found the answer here. Thanks to your post.